# AVD device has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm attempting to set up my development environment in an Azure virtual machine with the following requirements:

.net framework 4.6.2, Java 10.0.2, and Windows 10 Pro 21H2 gen 1 (Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044)
Processor:- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8370C CPU at 2.80GHz, 2793 MHz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s), 16 GB of RAM, and 128 GB of SDD

I installed Android Studio version 10 API level 29 with required SDK tools and components and also created a AVD and run the code and the error displays - AVD device has terminated.

Please let me know how this issue occurs and how to resolve.

Thanks & Regards,
Deepak Jha
Details

Comment: Does your Azure VM supports nested virtualization? You can run `emulator-check.exe hyper-v` to check availability of VM support.